# Weird UV after sculpting

Tags: uv

after sculpting in blender i tried to import my model to 3D coat and substance painter but it has weird UV that results a very bad texture.
how to fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Apply Transforms? idk, would be great to see uv screenshots within blender